# Html button in message to create another message

Tags: html, email, button, outlook

I need to create a button on the email message (Outlook) to replicate the existing message and allow me to forward it to the next person. I would need this to keep tracking emails. The flow would need to look like that:

The requester sends an email with a button to forward --> Doer will send email to the reviewer via clicking button --> Reviewer will send the email back to the requester via clicking button.

Each time the button would need to contain a code that would allow such tracking - for example, adding "DOER" and "REVIEWER" in the subject, respectively.

The problem I have (as I'm not a programmer) is that I know how to create a message with HTML, and I know how to insert a simple button into such a message. What I have no idea how to do, is putting such code of HTML email into this button code. I keep failing, unfortunately.

What I have is standard email body:

```
<p style="color:black;font-size:17px;font-family:calibri;">
  <style> table, th, td {border:  1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}
 </style>
  Hi&nbsp; <b>John,</b> <br /> <br /> Please review price for:<br /><br/> 
  <table style="width:100%">
    <tr>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>XXCode</th>
      <th>XXLevel</th>
      <th>XXTitle</th>
      <th>XXFamily</th>
      <th>XXCut</th>
      <th>XXMatch</th>
      <th>XXGrade</th>
      <th>XXXMatch</th>
      <th>XXXGrade</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td rowspan ="16">BRAZIL</td>
     </tr>
     <tr> 
      <td>10000XXX</td>
      <td>B</td>
      <td>Logistics</td>
      <td>Supply</td>
      <td>General</td>
      <td>ASCXXX</td>
      <td>7 | 8</td>
      <td>SCNXXXXX</td>
      <td>43 | 44 | 45 | 46</td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
   </table><br /><br /> The deadline for this task is: 
   <span style="background-color:yellow">26-8-2021, 10:16</span> <br /><br />
    After the task is done- please send a message to <a href=>@Anna, Jolen</a> for review.<br /><br />Thank you,<br /></p></p>
```

Button:

````
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="center" style="border-radius: 5px; background-color: #733658;">
            <a href="mailto:anna.jolen@company.com?CC=jola.zilen@company.com&subject=FW (&cell A520&) DOER& body=<html><body><b>blablabla</b></body></html>" target="_blank" style="font-size: 18px; font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; color: #ffffff; font-weight: bold; text-decoration: none;border-radius: 5px; padding: 12px 18px; border: 1px solid #733658; display: inline-block;">DOER'S RESPONSE &rarrhk;</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```


Many thanks,AM
````

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't support form's controls, nor allowing to run scripts on the message body for security reasons. You may consider developing an add-in for Outlook instead. It can be a COM add-in (VSTO) or web-based one to support multiple platforms.